# mp4 videos not supported by powerpoint

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I have used ffmpeg-2022-05-26 to convert simple .avi to .mp4 and these videos get supported on almost all platforms, including PowerPoint. When I updated ffmpeg to the version released around 2023-05-31, using the same conversion code, the mp4 videos are not supported by PowerPoint. Any suggestions will be helpful.